# PYTHON: No puedo instanciar metodos de otra clase, tengo el error ModuleNotFoundError:

Tags: python

IDE: Visual Studio Code

### DETALLE DE ERROR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Degreed\Python\Fundamentos\herencia_multiple\cuadrado.py", line 2, in 
from herencia_multiple.color import Color
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'herencia_multiple'

### Tengo una clase padre llamada (FiguraGeometrica)

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod 

class Figura_Geometrica(ABC):
    
    def __init__(self,alto,ancho):
        self.alto = alto
        self.ancho = ancho

@abstractmethod
def area(self):
    pass
```

### Otra clase padre llamada Color

```
class Color:
    def __init__(self,color):
        self.color = color
```

### Y una clase hija llamada cuadrado en donde voy a utilizar los atributos  de FiguraGeometrica y Color, pero al importar las clases, tengo este error, y creo es directamente desde la carpeta "Herencia_Multiple", pero no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, si quiero importar la clase directamente desde import, es decir sin el from, no me reconoce los atributos y metodos de la clase Padre:

```
from herencia_multiple.color import Color
from herencia_multiple.figura_geometrica import Figura_Geometrica


class Cuadrado(Figura_Geometrica, Color):
    
    def __init__(self,lado,color):
        Figura_Geometrica.__init__(self,lado,lado)
        Color.__init__(self,color)
    
    def calculo_area(self):
        return self.alto * self.ancho

cuadrado = Cuadrado(4,"Rojo")

print(cuadrado.calculo_area())
```

Comment: Prueba a añadir un fichero llamado `__init__.py` (aunque esté vacío) dentro de la carpeta `herencia_multiple`.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, ya agregue el fichero llamado  __init__.py (con 2 guiones bajos en cada lado) y  (vacío), dentro de la carpeta herencia_multiple, pero me sigue dando el mismo error :(, ya cerre el ID y lo volvì a abrir, esta es la primera vez que hago una importación de atributos y metodos de otra clase, no se si deba de instalar dentro del ID algo adicional.

Comment: Es bastante probable que se trate de que la carpeta desde la que se está lanzando el script no es la carpeta en la que reside el script. Esto ocurre si dentro de VSCode le das al botón "Play". Es mejor que abras una terminal, vayas (mediante `cd`) a la carpeta donde está tu script y desde allí ejecutes `python script`. Por defecto python busca módulos en la carpeta desde la que se lanza el script (además de en los lugares donde estén instalados "oficialmente" con pip)

Comment: No se si lo estoy haciendo bien, pero me sale el mismo error desde CMD:          C:\Degreed\Python\Fundamentos\herencia_multiple>dir
  Directorio de C:\Degreed\Python\Fundamentos\herencia_multiple

Comment: 27/01/2021  02:19 p. m.    <DIR>          .
27/01/2021  02:19 p. m.    <DIR>          ..
25/01/2021  11:25 p. m.                73 color.py
27/01/2021  02:30 p. m.               432 cuadrado.py
26/01/2021  10:43 p. m.               239 figura_geometrica.py
27/01/2021  01:58 p. m.               361 tempCodeRunnerFile.py
26/01/2021  10:44 p. m.               121 test_figura_geometrica.py
27/01/2021  12:50 a. m.               920 variables_clase.py

Comment: 27/01/2021  02:19 p. m.                 0 __init__.py
25/01/2021  11:59 p. m.    <DIR>          __pycache__
               7 archivos          2,146 bytes
               3 dirs  336,087,937,024 bytes libres

C:\Degreed\Python\Fundamentos\herencia_multiple>cuadrado.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Degreed\Python\Fundamentos\herencia_multiple\cuadrado.py", line 2, in <module>
    from herencia_multiple.color import Color
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'herencia_multiple'

Comment: No se si deba de hacer algún cambio en las variables de entorno de la PC.

Comment: No, pero la carpeta desde la que lo lanzas no puede ser `herencia_multiple`. Debes lanzarlo desde la carpeta "justo encima". Es decir, en una carpeta tendrás tu programa `script.py` que es el que ejecutas con python y hace import del resto, y una sub-carpeta de ella será `herencia_padre` con el resto de módulos. A menos que lo que estés intentando sea importar un módulo desde otro, ambos en `herencia_multiple`. En ese caso deberás poner `from .color import Color`, etc. Es decir, cambias `herencia_multiple` por `.`.

Comment: muchas gracias, cambie la rut de mi script y con eso ya corriò!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes que crear un fichero llamado **init**.py en tu carpeta de modulos y nunca ejecutes tus script dentro de esa misma hagalo en otra